# How to stop the handler here when the button will be clicked again?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to stop the thread handler manually when the button is clicked again. i am not able to get the solution anywhere please help.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.black:
            changecolor();
            Handler h = new Handler();
            h.postDelayed( new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    black.setBackgroundResource(R.color.black);
                }
            }, 2000);



           // h.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
/*I want to stop the handler here. please help.*/

             black.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);

            break;

        case R.id.blue:
            changecolor();
            Handler h1 = new Handler();
            h1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    blue.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue);
                }
            }, 2000);
            blue.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
            break;

        case R.id.green:
            changecolor();
            Handler h2 = new Handler();
            h2.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    green.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green);
                }
            }, 2000);
            green.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);

            break;

        case R.id.red:
            changecolor();
            Handler h3 = new Handler();
            h3.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    red.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
                }
            }, 2000);
            red.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);

            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: use handler.removeCallback()

Comment: use handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);

Comment: use handler.removeCallbacks(null)

Comment: i want to stop the thread that postdelayed method is using on another click within the delaytime in the postdelay method?? @DivyeshPatel

Comment: i want to stop the thread that postdelayed method is using on another click within the delaytime in the postdelay method?? @Rajasekhar

Comment: Store the `Handler` so that you can retrieve it at the second listener call, make an appropriate test and remove the callbacks if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way.

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Put your logic here
        }
    };

handler.postDelayed(runnable, INTERVAL_TIME);

handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```